# What is this wall texture called, and how is it applied?

Tags: plaster, patching-drywall, texture

It's the usual story, I need to do some repairs and want to match the existing texture. It is definitely some kind of applied finish, as all the walls have it regardless of whether they are plasterboard or concrete.

There are lots of posts asking this question, I checked all the ones I could find but none of them had this specific texture, but sorry if I missed it.

[image: all]

Comment: Are the flat spots raised above the finer texture or recessed? As in are the flat spots a result of the texture being applied over the surface and did not stay in the flat spot areas?

Comment: To me it looks like it was a wet splatter. One method is to shoot the mud wet, when it is done like this there is no knock down step. The gun is set on a finer setting, my gun has 3 or 4 orifice plates (the size exit hole) with wet you use a small one. The other setting is how far the piston pulls back with wet it depends but usually a smaller pull back , sometimes I will set it to full so I can go faster. Matching texture can take quite a while for the inexperienced, it’s best to have a piece of material to test on, spray , scrape off and try a different setting.

Comment: It reminds me of a real coarse sanded finish with parts removed

Comment: @jack the flat spots are raised

Comment: Knock down it is....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's *knockdown texture*.   According to [this introductory article](https://www.bobvila.com/articles/knockdown-texture/), it's easy for a homeowner to reproduce.  Good luck.

Comment: Thanks, that looks like it! I'll have a go